# How to add multiple tasks to the Parallel.Invoke without hardcoding?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am trying to understand the use-case for [Parallel.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke?view=net-6.0) which can take either array of actions or colon separated individual actions (since it uses `params`).

In the following code sample, parallel invocation happens for the static method, and lambda method, and one or more inline delegates. Suppose there are 5 more tasks that I want to run in parallel, then I will have to hardcode it as delegates (unlike suppose I had used Parallel.ForEach. How to add multiple tasks to the Parallel.Invoke without hardcoding?

```
static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                Parallel.Invoke(
                    BasicAction,    // Param #0 - static method
                    () =>           // Param #1 - lambda expression
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Method=beta, Thread={0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    },
                    delegate()      // Param #2 - in-line delegate
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Method=gamma, Thread={0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    }
                );
            }
            // No exception is expected in this example, but if one is still thrown from a task,
            // it will be wrapped in AggregateException and propagated to the main thread.
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An action has thrown an exception. THIS WAS UNEXPECTED.\n{0}", e.InnerException.ToString());
            }
        }

        static void BasicAction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method=alpha, Thread={0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }
```

For example - `Console.WriteLine("Method=beta, Thread={0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);` - the text inside `Console.WriteLine` can be parameterized and then we can use a Parallel.Foreach to loop over an array of strings and invoke the `Console.WriteLine`. Can this be done with `Parallel.Invoke`?

Comment: I've added link/summary of the documentation you referring to. Please review the edit and clarify what exactly you trying to understand. Maybe show code you would like to write and could not?

Comment: I have updated the question - For example - `Console.WriteLine("Method=beta, Thread={0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);` - the text inside `Console.WriteLine` can be parameterized and then we can use a Parallel.Foreach to loop over an array of strings and invoke the `Console.WriteLine`. Can this be done with `Parallel.Invoke`?

Comment: @variable what are you *actually* trying to do? What is the actual problem you want to solve? `Parallel.Invoke` is used very infrequently and is mainly a remnant from the days before `async/await`. The very fact you have to write so much code means it's not the write tool

Comment: @variable `Parallel.ForEach` isn't an alternative to `Parallel.Invoke`. `Parallel.ForEach` will partition the input data into roughly as many chunks as there are cores and use one worker task to process each partition, avoiding synchronization between workers. It's meant specifically for CPU-bound processing of a large volume of in-memory data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - are you saying Parallel.Invoke is meant for IO bound?

Comment: No, I'm saying it's rarely used since 2012. You can do the same things in better ways, especially since `async/await` became available. Even if you tried to use `Parallel.Invoke` as some sort of async work queue, there are better alternatives. .NET has high-level abstractions for dataflow, pipelines, data parallelism, asynchronous execution, event stream processing. In most cases you can solve your problem using the correct abstraction.

Comment: For example, instead of using `Parallel.Invoke` as a work queue you can use a Channel or an ActionBlock. Although an even better option would be to create a pipeline of processing blocks working on *messages*, not actions

Comment: Just out of interest - the other TPL things like Parallel.For and Parallel.ForEach are also rarely used? I mean are they also to be replaced with async/await/Task.Run.....?

Answer (score 0):

One of the [Parallel.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-parallel-invoke(system-action())) overloads has `params Action[]` as parameter. So it is possible to pass a simple array of actions to the method.

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
actions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine("Method 1"));
actions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine("Method2"));
// add more actions based on some conditions

Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray());
```